# how to insert data to uitableview from array?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I m retrieving data from sqlite table and filling it in tableview

```
//get notes saved to database
    NSString *selectQuery=@"select * from ATTACHABLEITEM where ATYPE='notes'";
    NSArray *notesarray=[delegate.database executeQuery:selectQuery];

    [table dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:notesarray];

this is going wrong.what is the right way to do so?
```

Comment: Assuming that notesarray gives you array of dictionaries, [dictionaryWithValuesForKeys] Returns a dictionary built from values obtained for the specified keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table views are a staple of iOS development. You should take time to learn how to use them.

You will find the following resources helpful:

- [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [UITableViewDataSource Protocol
  Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource)
- [UITableViewDelegate Protocol
  Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate)
- [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

Essentially, you create a table view and set delegate and datasource objects which respond to certain methods. These methods pertain to the configuration and content of the table view. The datesource is "consulted" for what data to display at a given index.